# standardMaterial using shaderMaterial. USE_MAP suddenly stopped working, "maptexelToLinear; no matching overloaded function found"

Tags: three.js

I am using the latest three.js build from github, it was updated the night before.

This code worked a few days back, but without changing the code this stopped working yesterday. It gives the error message `maptexelToLinear; no matching overloaded function found` on line 6 in the map_fragment shaderChunk:

```
vec4 texelColor = texture2D( map, vUv );
texelColor = mapTexelToLinear( texelColor ); //here
```

Did something change? Is this still the correct way of creating a standard material from a shadermaterial? With the defines, extensions and map uniform?

https://jsfiddle.net/EthanHermsey/c4sea1rg/119/

```
    let texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(

        document.getElementById( 'blockDiff' ).src

    );


    // this works fine
    /* let mat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {

           map: texture

    } ) */



    // this does not
    let mat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

        //custom shaders
        // vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'blockVertexShader' ).textContent,
        // fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'blockFragmentShader' ).textContent,

        //The standard shaders do not even work :/
        vertexShader: THREE.ShaderLib[ 'standard' ].vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: THREE.ShaderLib[ 'standard' ].fragmentShader,

        uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge( [

            THREE.ShaderLib[ 'standard' ].uniforms,
            {

                blockScale: { value: new THREE.Vector3() } // used in custom shaders

            }

        ] ),

        defines: {

            "STANDARD": '',
            "USE_UV": '',
            "USE_MAP": ''

        },

        lights: true

    } );

    mat.uniforms.map.value = texture;

    mat.extensions.derivatives = true;
    mat.uniformsNeedUpdate = true;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was actually an error in previous `three.js` versions that injected `maptexelToLinear()` with a wrong implementation into shader code. This problems was fixed with `r118`. However, it requires from user code that your custom shader material has a property called `map`.

Updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/og8Lmp6e/

In this way, it's also not necessary to set custom defines like `USE_MAP` or `USE_UV` anymore. That happens automatically. And of course the implementation of `maptexelToLinear()` now respects the encoding of your texture.

BTW: It's actually best to modify built-in materials with [Material.onBeforeCompile()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/Material.onBeforeCompile).

Comment: Oh this is perfect! Thanks so much. I like that modification, makes sense. 
Will use the onBeforeCompile :)

Comment: well. Three v137->v137.5 broke the shader-compile with the same error-msg ('mapTexelToLinear' : no matching overloaded function found). i changed nothing since v.137. same material, same texture. any hints?

Comment: With `r137`, any usage of `mapTexelToLinear()` can be removed. The entire GLSL inline decode is obsolete.

Comment: @Mugen87 wow. thats the solution. thank you! and thank you for your very fast answer.

Comment: You need to update the 2nd part of your answer to avoid misleading anyone reading this: as of r139, the `USE_MAP` **and** `USE_UV` are both required even for a simple thing as replicating a phong using a shader: `var m = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({uniforms: THREE.ShaderLib.phong.uniforms, defines: {USE_MAP: "", USE_UV: ""}, vertexShader: THREE.ShaderLib.phong.vertexShader, fragmentShader: THREE.ShaderLib.phong.fragmentShader, lights:true});`. I spent two days reading here before I got rid of the error by adding the latter define. Good idea to avoid custom defines, but sadly, not possible ATM.

Comment: Since there is no inline GLSL decode anymore (meaning `mapTexelToLinear()`) does no exist anymore), the entire thread is obsolete.